# Is there any difference between the two limits in $(1)$ and $(2)$ as above?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, limits, analysis

I read a a paper about statistics and machine learning ("[High-dimensional Asymptotics of Langevin Dynamics in Spiked Matrix Models](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2204.04476)"). Assume that $\{(Y_0^i, \sqrt{N}U^i)\}_{1\le i\le N}$ are iid, independent of Brownian motion $\{B_t\}_{t\ge 0}$. Assume that $E (Y_0^i)^2=1$, $E[U^i Y_0^i]=\frac{\rho \sqrt{\lambda}}{\sqrt{N}}$ for some $\rho \in [0,1]$, $\lambda>0$. Let $\sigma=[\sigma^1, \dots, \sigma^N]^T$ and assume that $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N \delta_{\sigma^i}\to\mu$ converges weakly to a probability measure $\mu$ with compact support.

On page 21, define the empirical measure
$$
\nu=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^N\delta_{Y_0^i,u^i, \sigma^i, B_{\cdot}^i}
$$
where the fourth marginal is an empirical distribution on the path sapce $C[0,T]$.

Take $f(Y_0, u, \sigma, B_\cdot)(w)=uY_0e^{w\sigma}$ which is $R^3\times C[0,T]\to C[0,T]$. Then
$$
\int fd\nu(w)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^Nf(Y_0, u, \sigma, B_\cdot)(w)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{i=1}^NuY_0e^{w\sigma}
$$

Since $\{(Y_0^i, \sqrt{N}U^i)\}_{1\le i\le N}$ are iid and first moment is finite, then from SLLN,
$$\int fd\nu(w)\to E[uY_0e^{w\sigma}]    \tag{1}$$ converges almost surely for any fixed $w\in [0,T]$. Here we think $\int fd\nu$ converges almost surely as a $C[0,T]$ valued random variable. We equip $C[0,T]$ with a sup-norm.

My question is why does the author introduce a Holder continuity property of $\int fd\nu$, uniformly in $N$? It says that "that allows us to bootstrap the above pointwise a.s. to a functional a.s. convergence statement". The Holder continuity property is as follows. For sufficiently large $N$, there exist $C, \alpha>0$, independent of $N$ such that a.s. for any $x,y\in [0,T]$,
$$
\left|\int fd\nu(x)-\int fd\nu(y)\right|\le C\|x-y\|^\alpha
$$

Then we can establish convergence of $$\int fd\nu \to E\int fd\nu \tag{2}$$

Is there any difference between the two limits in $(1)$ and $(2)$ as above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the paper you mentioned, in convergence (1), where the author called it the first step, it is a point-wise convergence, means *for any fixed* $t\in[0,T]$,
$$\biggl|\int fd\nu(t)-\mathbb{E}\biggl[\int fd\nu\biggr](t)\biggr|\to_{a.s.}0.$$
The convergence (2) is in a functional sense, using sup-norm, as you said,
$$\sup_{t\in[0,T]}\biggl|\int fd\nu(t)-\mathbb{E}\biggl[\int fd\nu\biggr](t)\biggr|\to_{a.s.}0.$$
Clearly the latter one is stronger than the first one. For example, pick a sequence $t_{n}$ on $[0,T]$ such that $t_{n}\neq t_{m}$ whenever $n\neq m$, let $g_{n}(t)=1$ if $t=t_{n}$ and $g_{n}(t)=0$ otherwise. Then you have $g_{n}(t)\to 0$ for any fixed $t$, but $\sup_{t\in[0,T]}g_{n}(t)=1\not\to0$. Hölder continuity condition rules out this class of non-smooth function, hence can make sure the convergence holds in a functional sense.

Comment: Thanks! But I am confused if we need to establish the second type limit? If we need the result that $\int fd\nu\to E[\int f d\nu]$ almost surely. It seems that for $\int f d\nu(w)$, we can just apply the SLLN, then we can get the limit. Do we really need the uniformly convergence in $w$?

Comment: @Hermi Certain operators are continuous under uniform topology, but not if the convergence holds only pointwise. For example argmin/argmax, if you have $g_{n}(x)\to g(x)$ uniformly over $x\in\mathcal{X}$, then you can conclude that $\arg\max g_{n}(x)\to \arg\max g(x)$ by continuous mapping theorem.